# How to configure SMTP for Ruby on Rails Action Mailer with custom domain and server settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, smtp

I am trying to set up Action Mailer for a Rails app with the following information:

- Username: info@custom_domain.io
- Password: XXX
- Incoming Server: mail.custom_domain.io
- IMAP Port: 993
- POP3 Port: 995
- Outgoing Server: mail.custom_domain.io
- SMTP Port: 465

This is what I have added up to now:

```
# config/initializers/smtp.rb
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address: "mail.custom_domain.io",
  port: 465,
  domain: "custom_domain.io",
  user_name: "info@custom_domain.io",
  password: "XXX",
  authentication: :login,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "https://custom_domain.io/" }
```

```
# app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'info@custom_domain.io'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.mailer_sender = 'info@custom_domain.io'
```

It does not work and I these are some of the lines printed in the heroku application log when I try to receive a devise "Forgot your password?" email:

- Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 1.5ms
- heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/users/password" host=(...).herokuapp.com request_id=57feaa71-b163-4da4-a9be-88669a6989ec fwd="85.240.151.227" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
- INFO -- : [...] Delivered mail 6258432c46533_4188f89122@3f915e09-a7c0-4794-a850-35dd51222c9b.mail (60145.5ms)
- Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 60466ms
- Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout with #TCPSocket:(closed)):

Comment: you are getting a 503 error -- the server is not ready to handle the request, but that looks like it has to do with your app not the mailer.  Including parts of the log does not provide the context necessary to help.

Answer (score -3):

try :
(i create a smtp_settings.yml with parameters but you can do as well if u wants)

smtp.rb :

```
SMTP_SETTINGS = YAML.load_file("#. 
    {Rails.root.to_s}/config/smtp_settings.yml"). 
    [Rails.env].deep_symbolize_keys

   ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address: SMTP_SETTINGS[:address],
    port: SMTP_SETTINGS[:port],
    domain: SMTP_SETTINGS[:domain],
    user_name: SMTP_SETTINGS[:username],
    password: SMTP_SETTINGS[:password],
    authentication: SMTP_SETTINGS[:authentication],
    enable_starttls_auto: SMTP_SETTINGS[:enable_starttls_auto]
    }
```

dont forget the configs on production/development.rb